# Rephrasing probabilities combinatorically

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Assume we have a bucket of 100 balls, 30 of which are yellow and 70 of which are blue. The probability of selecting a yellow ball is of course:

30/100 = 0.3.

I'm wondering if it would be appropriate to think of this question combinatorically, too, like this:

$\frac{the \ number \ of \ ways \ to \ select \ 1 \ ball \ from \ 30}{the \ number \ of \ ways \ to \ select \ 1 \ ball \ from \ 100}$

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.
$$\dfrac{\binom {30} 1}{\binom{100}1}=\dfrac{3}{10}$$

---

Likewise, for instance, the probability for obtaining two yellow balls when selecting two balls.$$\dfrac{\binom{30}2}{\binom{100}2}=\dfrac{30\cdot29}{100\cdot 99}$$